# Why EXPLAIN SQL result for KEY is NULL

Tags: mysql, explain

I have created INDEX for my table but when use explain QUERY the result for key is NULL.

my table as below:

TABLE list_country

- id
- id_tx
- id_ref_country   FK TO id in ref_country
- cost
- cceiling

INDEX FOR list_country:

- id                       PRIMARY
- id_tx,id_ref_country     UNIQUE
- id_tx                    KEY
- id_ref_country           KEY

TABLE ref_country

- id
- country_name

INDEX for ref_country:

- id                    PRIMARY

i run explain query as below:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT ctr.id_tx
, GROUP_CONCAT(rctr.country_name,':',cost) AS cost_country
, GROUP_CONCAT(rctr.country_name,':',cceiling) AS ceiling_country
, GROUP_CONCAT(rctr.country_name) AS country 
FROM list_country ctr
LEFT JOIN ref_country rctr ON rctr.id = ctr.id_ref_country 
GROUP BY id_tx
```

RESULT EXPLAIN FOR TABLE list_country TYPE = ALL,  KEY = NULL

Why the key is null for list_country even i specify the index?

The DDL for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `list_country` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_tx` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_ref_country` INT NOT NULL,
  `cost` DECIMAL(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cceiling` DECIMAL(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `country_unik` (`id_tx`,`id_ref_country`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `id_tx` (`id_tx`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `id_ref_country` (`id_ref_country`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `list_country_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tx`) REFERENCES `ep_tx` (`id_tx`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `list_country_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_ref_country`) REFERENCES `ref_country` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=55609 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: While writing in all upper-case is common for SQL, please don't use it for normal text (like your title). Then it's considered shouting, and shouting at people is rude.

Comment: hi @Someprogrammerdude. tq for the advise and guidance.

Comment: Please post, with this kind of questions, the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE list_country`.

Comment: To answer you question: Because all records must be read (there is no WHERE-clause), MySQL _thinks_ it's good enough to just read all records, and for that no index is needed.

Comment: @Luuk, i post it above coz comment only allow certain limit.

Comment: @Luuk, tq for the info.

Comment: @wanna: Comment are, by no means, meant to post code in. Thanks for updating the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the results for you query, MySSQL needs to get the info of the following fields:

- ctr.id_tx
- ctr.id_ref_country

Because of this, only the index `country_unik` can be used, it contains both fields, or MySQL can just read the complete table.

[EXPLAIN Output Format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#jointype_all) says, about Type=ALL:

> A full table scan is done for each combination of rows from the
> previous tables. This is normally not good if the table is the first
> table not marked const, and usually very bad in all other cases.
> Normally, you can avoid ALL by adding indexes that enable row
> retrieval from the table based on constant values or column values
> from earlier tables.

MySQL is avoiding the use of the index, because it needs all records for that table.